# Unable to run Tomcat on https with a hostname set on “C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts” file. Unsupported protocol

Tags: tomcat, https

I am trying to run Tomcat(version 9.0.37) on https with a hostname set on “C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts” file (ie. not with https://localhost:8443.)

I added an entry “  OTDS“ to my machine`s hosts (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts).

I can ping OTDS and it gives proper response.
I ran the following command to generate a jks Keystore for my tomcat (version 9.0.37).

```
keytool -genkey -keystore  "C:\mycompany\certs\otds\otds.jks" -alias otds -storepass password -dname "CN=otds, OU=IT, O=myfirm, L=Toronto, S=Ontario, C=CA"
```

Java running on my machine:
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)

Entries in my tomcat`s config/server.xml file.

```
<Connector port="8090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
               

    <Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="C:\Desjardins\certs\otds\otds.jks" keystorePass="password"
           clientAuth="false" 
           sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"
              sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
              ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
                       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
                       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
               />
```

When I access tomcat with `https://otds:8443` in chrome. I get the following error:

Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.

I would very much appreciate it if someone can provide me some direction on how to get around this.

Comment: Why are you disabling TLS 1.3? Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried enabling TLS 1.3 as well but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around this issue when I added "-keyalg RSA" parameter to my "keytool -genkey" command.

ie.
keytool -genkey -keystore  "C:\company\certs\otds\otds.jks" -keyalg RSA -alias otds -storepass password -dname "CN=otds, OU=IT, O=myfirm, L=Toronto, S=Ontario, C=CA"

Comment: When you don't specify the key algorithm, Java 11 generates a DSA key, which is very uncommon: look for the [cipher suites](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/ciphers.html) with DSS in their name.